# Django: How to use select_related to INNER JOIN FK's FK

Tags: python, django

**29 Dec: updated models**

I have got three models as follows:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    job_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)

class Project(models.Model):
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, null=True) # updated (null=True)***
    source = models.ForeignKey(Source) # added***

class Task(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)

class Source(models.Model): # added***
    blahblah...
```

And I would like to get the job number for a task. Something like below:

```
job = Job.objects.all().select_related()
jobno = job[0].project.job.job_number
```

I'm not sure how many times the query above will hit the DB. But I guess it will be more than twice, won't it?

`select_related` can only pre-cache the foreign key for 2 tables to my understanding. Any one can suggest the best practice in this case to reduce the number of times hitting the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select_related()` joins all these three models in one query:

```
>>> from app.models import Task
>>> task = Task.objects.all().select_related()[0]
>>> task.project.job.job_number
u'123'
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> len(connection.queries)
1
>>> connection.queries
[{u'time': u'0.002', u'sql': u'QUERY = u\'SELECT "app_task"."id", "app_task"."project_id", "app_project"."id", "app_project"."job_id", "app_job"."job_number" FROM "app_task" INNER JOIN "app_project" ON ( "app_task"."project_id" = "app_project"."id" ) INNER JOIN "app_job" ON ( "app_project"."job_id" = "app_job"."job_number" ) LIMIT 1\' - PARAMS = ()'}]
>>>
```

Readable SQL:

```
SELECT "app_task"."id", "app_task"."project_id", "app_project"."id",
       "app_project"."job_id", "app_job"."job_number"
FROM "app_task"
INNER JOIN "app_project" ON ( "app_task"."project_id" = "app_project"."id" )
INNER JOIN "app_job" ON ( "app_project"."job_id" = "app_job"."job_number" )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But when I tried the `len(connection.queries)` in the shell, I got 2. That means it has hit the DB twice. Any idea?

Comment: `queries` list contains all SQL smetements executed during current session. May be you did other lookup or object creation?  Print the `connection.queries` list to see the second SQL query.

Comment: I have checked the `connection.queries`.
The first query selects the Task table and its directly related tables. The second query selects the Job table that is related to Project that is related to Task.

Comment: Which version of Django you use? The code from my answer is executed in 1.7

Comment: Mine is 1.6.1 . Is the behaviour of select_related changed in 1.7?

Comment: Now I ran this code against django 1.6.1 and got the same result as with 1.7 - single query with two INNER JOIN's. Are you sure that you executed the exact shell statements as in my answer? Can you update the question with full log of your `manage.py shell` session?

Comment: Thanks @catavaran. I tried to run it from scratch (from building the models) and got the same result! That means `select_related` actually will INNER JOIN FK's FK:) But it didn't work for my case. I guess it's because I've got two FKs in a model. I have updated the models. In my `manage.py shell` log, it only INNER JOIN'ed the Source table, not the Job table. Hence hit DB twice. Any idea?

Comment: Oh, you added `null=True` to `Project.job` field. This is the reason of you problem - Django can't use **INNER** JOIN here. AFAIK Django doesn't support OUTER JOINs so you have to load `Jobs` by separate query and manually attach them to related `Projects`.  Or you can try to use `prefetch_related()` somehow.

Comment: You are right! That's exactly why job is not INNER JOIN'ed. Thanks for you help @catavaran !

Answer (score 1):

You can use a filter:

```
task = Task.objects.all().select_related().filter(
    project__id__isnull=False, 
    job__id__isnull=False)
```